# Code first The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I just started using Code first approach for creating databases. I have following 3 tables :

```
public class TagDatabase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TagTypes")]
    public virtual int TagTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TagTypesDb> TagTypes { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual UsersDb Users { get; set; }
}

public class TagTypesDb
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagTypeID { get; set; }
    public string TagTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class UsersDb
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Here TagDatabse and User and TagType have 1 to 1 replationship. The fluent API code which i used for this is :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<TagDatabase>()
           .HasOptional(a => a.TagTypes)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(u => u.TagTypeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TagDatabase>()
                    .HasRequired(a => a.Users)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(u => u.CreatedBy);
}
```

Now my issue is whenever i am trying to insert data in TagDatabase i got this exception :

```
TagDatabase_TagTypes: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'TagDatabase_TagTypes_Target' in relationship 'TagDatabase_TagTypes'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
```

The TagTypeId property is allowed nulls .so i used HasOptional() in OnModelCreating method.

Cananybody please tell me how to solve this issue and what i am missing here ?

Comment: If you say `HasOptional(a => a.TagTypes)`, you should make the foreign key `TagTypeID` nullable.

Comment: The TagTypeId is nullable type in TagDatabase. So i used  HasOptional(a => a.TagTypes) .This is correct or not

Comment: Your property is not. `TagTypeID` property of `TagDatabase` should be `int?` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the foreign key property `nullable` if the corresponding relationship is optional.

```
public class TagDatabase
{
  //sniff...

 [ForeignKey("TagTypes")]
 public virtual int? TagTypeID { get; set; }      //Since TagTypes is optional, this should be nullable
 public virtual ICollection<TagTypesDb> TagTypes { get; set; }

 //sniff...
}
```